# Wifi stops working after every reboot on Ubuntu 17.04 on Macbook Pro mid 2010

Tags: drivers, wireless, broadcom, macbook

I am having some problems with my wifi on an Macbook Pro 13" mid 2010 with Ubuntu 17.04.
I Just installed Ubuntu yesterday (so it's fresh).
I went to the system settings/Software & Updates/Additional drivers and selected a proprietary driver for the wifi-card. (The drivers is: Broadcom Limited: BCM4322).
And the the wifi starts working.
BUT after I poweroff the computer and starts it again the wifi is no longer working. It can't find any wifi-spots.
If I go back into "Additional drivers", deactivate the driver, restart the computer and back in to "Additional drivers" and activate the Broadcom driver it works again. But just until next restart...

Anyone who knows what to do?
Thanks!

**Edit 1**

Output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list`

```
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Limited BCM4322 802.11a/b/g/n Wireless LAN Controller [14e4:432b] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Apple Inc. AirPort Extreme [106b:008d]
    Kernel driver in use: wl
    Kernel modules: ssb, wl
03:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Broadcom Limited NetXtreme BCM5764M Gigabit Ethernet PCIe [14e4:1684] (rev 10)
    Subsystem: Broadcom Limited NetXtreme BCM5764M Gigabit Ethernet PCIe [14e4:1684]
    Kernel driver in use: tg3
    Kernel modules: tg3
04:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: NVIDIA Corporation MCP89 [GeForce 320M] [10de:08a0] (rev a2)
0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
2: brcmwl-0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

Comment: I bet you can run `systemctl restart network-manager` instead of re-installing the drivers. It is a suspend issue.

Comment: No a `systemctl restart network-manager` doesn't work.
It only works when the driver just have been activated. After a reboot or after the networkmanager has been restarted it doesn't work any longer.

Comment: does the sudo rmmod brcmsmac and aftrewards the sudo modprobe brcmsmac entered in terminal change the situation?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list` terminal command.

Comment: @kukulo -  sudo rmmod brcmsmac returns:
rmmod: ERROR: Module brcmsmac is not currently loaded

Comment: @Pilot6 - I've updated the question with the output.

Thanks all for helping!